# Intercepting cuda memory management related APIs in cuda11.7 and encountering invalid device context (201) errors

Tags: cuda, runtime-error, hook, cuda-context

I implemented an interception library that intercepts the driver API `cuMemAlloc()` and `cuGetProcAddress()` and then forwards it. Then I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path of the interception library and run a matrix multiplication program written with the runtime API. When the program calls `cudaMalloc ()`, the driver layer API `cuGetProcAddress()` will be called internally to obtain the function address of `cuMemAlloc()` to call `cuMemAlloc()`, so I intercepted cuGetProcAddress and changed the cuMemAlloc function address it obtained to the `cuMemAlloc` function address of my interception library, the function can be intercepted at this time, but a 201 error is returned after calling the original library function through `dlsym`. How can I solve this problem? Is my interception process correct?
My code is as follows

- hook library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum cudaError_enum {
    CUDA_SUCCESS                              = 0,
    //...
    //...Not copied completely from my code
    //...
    CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN                        = 999
} CUresult;

typedef unsigned long long CUdeviceptr_v2;
typedef CUdeviceptr_v2 CUdeviceptr;
typedef uint64_t cuuint64_t;
char *cuda_filename = "libcuda.so.515.65.01";


CUresult cuMemAlloc(CUdeviceptr *dptr, size_t bytesize){
        printf("hijacking cuMemAlloc!\n");
        CUresult (*hello)(CUdeviceptr *, size_t);
        CUresult ret;
        void *table = NULL;

        table = dlopen(cuda_filename, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_NODELETE);
        if (!table) {
                printf("Error can't find library %s", cuda_filename);
        }
        hello = (CUresult (*)(CUdeviceptr *, size_t))dlsym(table, "cuMemAlloc");
        if (!hello){
                printf("can't find function cuMemAlloc");
        }
        ret = hello(dptr, bytesize);


        return ret;
}


CUresult cuGetProcAddress(const char *symbol, void **pfn, int cudaVersion, cuuint64_t flags){
        //printf("hijacking cuGetProcAddress!\n");
        CUresult (*hello)(const char *, void **, int, cuuint64_t);
        CUresult ret;
        void *table = NULL;

        table = dlopen(cuda_filename, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_NODELETE);
        if (!table) {
                printf("Error can't find library %s", cuda_filename);
        }
        hello = (CUresult (*)(const char *, void **, int, cuuint64_t))dlsym(table, "cuGetProcAddress");
        if (!hello){
                printf("can't find function cuGetProcAddress");
        }
        ret = hello(symbol, pfn, cudaVersion, flags);
        if (!strcmp(symbol, "cuGetProcAddress"))
                *pfn = cuGetProcAddress;
        if (!strcmp(symbol, "cuMemAlloc"))
                *pfn = cuMemAlloc;

        return ret;
}
```

- compile and export

```
gcc hook.c -fPIC -shared -ldl -o libcuda.so.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD
```

- runtime application

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int Row=2048;
const int Col=2048;

__global__
void matrix_mul_gpu(int *M, int* N, int* P, int width)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<width;k++)
    {
        int a = M[j*width+k];
        int b = N[k*width+i];
        sum += a*b;
    }
    P[j*width+i] = sum;
}

int main()
{
            cudaError_t cuda_err = cudaSuccess;
            printf("func start \n");
            int *A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * Row * Col);
            int *B = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * Row * Col);
            int *C = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * Row * Col);
            //malloc device memory
            int *d_dataA, *d_dataB, *d_dataC;
            printf("before cudaMalloc()\n");
            cuda_err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dataA, sizeof(int) *Row*Col);
            //cuda_err = cudaGetLastError();
            if (cudaSuccess != cuda_err)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "(%s:%s:%d)",  __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cuda_err));
                    printf("cuda_err is %d\n", cuda_err);
                    exit(1);
            }
            printf("after cudaMalloc()\n");
            cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dataB, sizeof(int) *Row*Col);
            cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dataC, sizeof(int) *Row*Col);
            //set value
            for (int i = 0; i < Row*Col; i++) {
                A[i] = 90;
                B[i] = 10;
            }

            cudaMemcpy(d_dataA, A, sizeof(int) * Row * Col, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            cudaMemcpy(d_dataB, B, sizeof(int) * Row * Col, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            dim3 threadPerBlock(16, 16);
            dim3 blockNumber((Col+threadPerBlock.x-1)/ threadPerBlock.x, (Row+threadPerBlock.y-1)/ threadPerBlock.y );
            matrix_mul_gpu << <blockNumber, threadPerBlock >> > (d_dataA, d_dataB, d_dataC, Col);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            cudaMemcpy(C, d_dataC, sizeof(int) * Row * Col, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            free(A);
            free(B);
            free(C);
            cudaFree(d_dataA);
            cudaFree(d_dataB);
            cudaFree(d_dataC);

    return 0;
}
```

- error output

```
nvcc matri.cu -o matri.out
./matri.out

func start
before cudaMalloc()
hijacking cuMemAlloc!
(matri.cu:main:40)invalid device context
cuda_err is 201
```

Comment: thanks, I've made changes.Do you know how to solve my question?Or is there any article I can refer to?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not an expert on driver stuff or interception. I just wanted to spare you being downvoted for posting images.